# How to get the "absolute" position of an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some elements positioned via CSS this way:

```
#myItem{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -350px;
}
```

I'd like to get their distance from  top and left  margin of the **page**.
How can I get those measure with javascript/jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's

[.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

and

[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

EDIT: As mentioned by @Nick, .offset() is what you want if you need the position relative to the document

```
$("#myItem").offset().top;
```

Comment: `.position()` is not correct for this, it's relative to the offset parent, not the page like the OP is after.

Comment: @Nick, indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.  I did still want to inform the poster of both methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for this:

```
var offset = $("#myItem").offset();
//use offset.left, offset.top
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jR6be/).